Sequelize Error: Restaurant.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model when importing Order model
I recently added a new model called Order to my project and successfully migrated it. However, the system does not seem to recognize it as a model. When I import it into my index.js file, it doesn't appear with the same syntax highlighting as the other models, as shown in the following image::

here is a quick image of all my models:

and what's odd is that when I try to import it to other models such as Restaurant.js and User.js, the code throws the following error:

Restaurant.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

What I have tried to do

Restart the server
check the spelling of the Order imports
I have tried commenting out import statements of the Order model which works, the puzzling part is that when those parts aren't commented out, the code throws an error unrelated to the Order model.

The following model definitions are how they are when I get the error:
models/Order.js:
const {Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize")
const sequelize = require('./database');
const User = require('./User');
const Restaurant = require("./Restaurant");


const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {

    //model fields and what no

}, { timestamps: true,

});

Order.belongsTo(Restaurant, {foreignKey: 'restaurantId'});
Order.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'customerId'});

module.exports = Order;


models/User.js:
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize") 
const sequelize = require('./database'); 

const Order = require('../models/Order.js'); //if this line is deleted, the error goes away


const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    //model fields and what not

});

User.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: 'customerId' });

module.exports = User;


models/Restaurant.js:
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize") 
const sequelize = require('./database'); 
const User = require("./User");

const Order = require('../models/Order.js'); //if this line is deleted, error goes away

const Restaurant = sequelize.define('Restaurant', {
    //model fields and what not

});

Restaurant.belongsTo(User); //error references this line when I try to add Order import line, despite this line having nothing to do with Order
Restaurant.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: 'restaurantId' });
module.exports = Restaurant;


I have posted my answer,please check and let me know your feedback.Thanks

This is clearly the case of circular-dependency. It happens when two or more  modules depend on each other, creating a loop that can lead to undefined or incomplete imports. You will get plenty of resources available online on this topic.
In your case Restaurant.js imports Order.js  which imports Restaurant.js again. So you are getting this error.
Solution:-

First modify accordingly both of your model files(Restaurant.js & Order.js) in order to avoid circular dependency.
Then create a new file where you can define the relationship or association like this.

relation.js
const Restaurant = require('./Restaurant');
const Order = require('./Order');
const User = require('./User');

function setupAssociations() {
    //--your code to define relationship among the models--//
}
module.exports = setupAssociations;`

After creating this relation.js import it into your main entry file i.e. app.js or index.js.
Try this , it will resolve your issue for sure.

Thanks a lot for the help, I was unaware of the circular dependency issue, your answer was very helpful!

@HamzahAlkhateeb, You are welcome.
